# fatal error. launching activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I want to access Confirmation activity from login activity. i was able to launch confirmation activity when i didn't have login and registration activity. login and registration works perfect without confirmation activity. and dashboard activity and confirmation activity works perfect without login and registration activity.

```
    Registration Activity.



    package com.example.androidhive;        
        import org.json.JSONException;
        import org.json.JSONObject;
        import com.example.androidhive.library.DatabaseHandler;
        import com.example.androidhive.library.UserFunctions;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnRegister;
    Button btnLinkToLogin;
    EditText inputFullName;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    TextView registerErrorMsg;

    // JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);
        registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

        // Register Button Click event
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);

                // check for login response
                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                            // user successfully registred
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        
                            // Launch Dashboard Screen
                            Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                            // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                            dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(dashboard);
                            // Close Registration Screen
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            // Error in registration
                            registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // Link to Login Screen
        btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                // Close Registration View
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
        }


Login Activity:- 

        import java.util.HashMap;
        import org.json.JSONException;
        import org.json.JSONObject;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import com.example.androidhive.library.DatabaseHandler;
        import com.example.androidhive.library.UserFunctions;

        public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnLogin;
    Button btnLinkToRegister;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    TextView loginErrorMsg;

    // JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
        loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                Log.d("Button", "Login");
                JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

                // check for login response
                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                            // user successfully logged in
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        

                            // Launch Dashboard Screen
                            Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                            // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                            dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(dashboard);

                            // Close Login Screen
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            // Error in login
                            loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
        }

Dashboard Activity:- 

        package com.example.androidhive;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import com.example.androidhive.ConfirmationActivity;
        import com.example.androidhive.R;
        import android.content.Context; 
        import android.content.Intent; 
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View; 
        import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
        import android.webkit.JsResult;
        import android.webkit.WebChromeClient; 
        import android.webkit.WebView;  
        import android.widget.Toast;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import com.example.androidhive.library.UserFunctions;
        public class DashboardActivity extends Activity {
    UserFunctions userFunctions;
    Button btnLogout;
    private String resultString="";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /**
         * Dashboard Screen for the application
         * */        
        // Check login status in database
        userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
        if(userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())){
            setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);
            btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
            btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    userFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                    login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(login);
                    // Closing dashboard screen
                    finish();
                }
            });

        }else{
            // user is not logged in show login screen
            Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(login);
            // Closing dashboard screen
            finish();
        }




    }


    public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        /** Show a toast from the web page */
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showToast(String toast) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode==0)
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //Use Data to get string
                resultString = data.getStringExtra("RESULT_STRING");
                LaunchWebView(resultString); 

            }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    private void LaunchWebView(String resultString)
    {
        WebView engine=(WebView)findViewById(com.example.androidhive.R.id.web_engine);
        //engine.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
        String[] array=resultString.split(":");
        engine.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true); 
        //engine.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        engine.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        engine.setWebChromeClient(new MyJavaScriptChromeClient()); 
        engine.loadUrl("http://74.101.168.139/snapshot.cgi?user="+array[0]+"&pwd="+array[1]+"&count=0" + "&resolution=32"+ "&rate=6"); 

    } 
    public void btnRefresh_ClicHandler(View view)
    {
        if(resultString!="")
            LaunchWebView(resultString);

    }
    public void btnHome(View arg)
    { 
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,ConfirmationActivity.class); 
        int result=0; 
        startActivityForResult(intent, result); 
    }

    private class MyJavaScriptChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,
                JsResult result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.onJsAlert(view, null, message, result);
        }  

    }  
        }


Confirmation Activity : -

        package com.example.androidhive;
        import com.example.androidhive.R;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        public class ConfirmationActivity extends Activity {

    EditText txtPassword=null;
    EditText txtUsername=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirmation);

    }
     public static final class menu2 {
            public static final int confirmation=0x7f080000;
        }

    @Override

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(menu2.confirmation, menu);
        return true;
    }
     public void btnCancel_ClickHandler(View arg)
     {

         finish();
     }
        public void btnOk_ClickHandler(View arg)
        {
            txtUsername=(EditText)findViewById(com.example.androidhive.R.id.txtUserName);
             txtPassword=(EditText)findViewById(com.example.androidhive.R.id.txtPassword); 
         if(txtUsername.getText().length()==0)
         {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                 "User name can not be empty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
             return;
         }

         if(txtPassword.getText().length()==0)
         {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                     "Password can not be empty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
             return;
         }


         Intent intent=new Intent();
         intent.putExtra("RESULT_STRING",txtUsername.getText()+ ":"+txtPassword.getText());
         setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
         finish();

    }
        }

Android Manifest. 

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidhive"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
      <uses-sdk  android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18"/> 
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".DashboardActivity" >

        </activity>
         <!--  Confirmation Activity -->
         <activity
            android:label="Confiramtion Activity" 
            android:name=".ConfiramtionActivity"></activity>
        <!--  Login Activity -->
        <activity
            android:label="Login Account" 
            android:name=".LoginActivity"></activity>

        <!--  Register Activity -->
        <activity
            android:label="Register New Account" 
            android:name=".RegisterActivity">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>




Android Fatal Error PLeaseeee Help:- 

        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at                 android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at com.example.androidhive.library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:47)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at com.example.androidhive.library.UserFunctions.loginUser(UserFunctions.java:32)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at com.example.androidhive.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:61)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        11-15 16:55:40.948: E/AndroidRuntime(858): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The only place I see you starting ConfirmationActivity (assuming your lack of proper indenting hasn't confused me) is in DashboardActivity.btnHome().

Comment: sorry my first time ever to post any question about anything online.
plus i am beginner in java and android. i was able to run 2 application separately and perfectly. i was also able to get the dashboard activity started until i added extra things. i for sure know there is some silly mistake , because code is good. 
please i am really confused and this is for my final year project.

Comment: Which instruction causes the exception, and what exception is it?  You get answers much faster when you post the specifics of your problem instead of pages of code.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown when application tries to access network in main thread. This is forbidden as accessing resources over network may take indefinite amount of time and your main thread will be blocked untill network operation finishes, thus making your app frozen to the user.

Instead in your `onClick()` method you should start a new [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which will do the networking. After the task finishes proceed with updating the ui (changing activity etc.).